# autorebuild of SCR Task in SSIS after XML code replacement

Tags: ssis, variables

I was wondering if doing operations such as **changing var in a SSIS** editing the xml code, rather than the cumbersome var rename/replacing in bids, if was possible to force to rebuild all the SCR task scripts that are actually using the vars. I noticed that the built version of the Tasks stored in the package are not updated so I need to open and close each of them to rebuild the tasks using the changes. Is there any option to force to rebuild all of them ?
Mario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing built into SSIS to automatically rebuild Script Components or Transformations.

However, there are third party tools that offer that functionality. My shop is currently using [Pragmatic Works' BIxPress](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-xPress/Features/CompileScriptTasks.aspx). I've found it very helpful, although not cheap; see their website for details.